# How can i fix this error? Class "App\Department" not found (View: E:\proiecte\HRmanagement-app\resources\views\admin\user\create.blade.php)

Tags: php, html, laravel, class

Can you please help me with this error Class "APP\Department" not found (View: E:\proiecte\HRmanagement-app\resources\views\admin\user\create.blade.php). I'm trying to do a HR management App. And in my form I want to bring sa departments and rols.

Here is my UserControle

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Department;
use App\Role;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    //am creat functia pentru a afisa departamentele
    
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        
        return view('admin.user.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'firstname'=>'required',
            'lastname'=>'required',
            'email'=> 'required | string | email | max:255 | unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|string',
            'department_id'=>'required',
            'role_id'=>'required',
            'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
            'start_from'=>'required',
            'designation'=>'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

my create.blade.php

```
    use App\Department;
@extends('admin.layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container mt-5">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Register employee
                    
                </li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
        <form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">General Information</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Mobile number </label>
                        <input type="number" name="mobile_number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Department</label>
                         <select class="form-control" name="department_id"  required="">
                             
                           @foreach(APP\Department::all() as $department)
                            <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
                           @endforeach
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Designation</label>
                        <input type="text" name="designation" class="form-control" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start date</label>
                        <input type="date" name="start_from" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" accept="image/*" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Login Information</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Role</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="role_id" required="">
                        @foreach(App\Role::all() as $role)
                            <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach 
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</form>
</div>
    
@endsection
```

and web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::post('departments','Departmentcontroller@store');
Route::resource('departments', 'Departmentcontroller');
Route::view('hrmanagement-app','admin.create');
Route::post('roles','RoleController@store');
Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
Route::post('users','UserController@store');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Comment: Where is located your model Departure?

Comment: if you are referr of department is in \app\Models\Department.php

Comment: you should change namespace in Department to `namespace App\Models` then use `App\Models\Department` in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to use model in view. This is not a standard way to implement models in view and not secure.

**Remove**     `use App\Department;` from create.blade.php

**You already mentioned your model in controller so it will works fine.**

```html
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Department; 
use App\Role;
```

**Do like this in your controller change create method**

```html
 public function create()
    {
        $departments = Department::get()->all();
        
        return view('admin.user.create', compact('departments'));
    }
```

**Changes these lines from** `create.blade.php`

```html
@foreach($departments as $department)
     <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Remove this lines from your** `web.php`

```
Route::post('departments','Departmentcontroller@store');
```

this line will do everything like loading index, create or update page, even they store or update and delete as well

Comment: if your problem get solved can you approve my answer by clicking on correction or right icon.

Comment: Hy! now I get "Error
Class "App\Department" not found"

Comment: It's ok. I've change the "use app\Department" to "use App\Models\Department;"

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. @PopaVasile I was Busy. I am glad to see you have found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `create.blade.php` blade:

```
@foreach(APP\Department::all() as $department)
    <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

You are using **APP**\Department::all(), with all caps. Instead, use this:

```
@foreach(App\Department::all() as $department)
    <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It not working. It gives me the same error, only now whit smal "P".

Comment: It's ok. I've change the "use app\Department" to "use App\Models\Department;"

Answer (score 0):

You have `APP\Department` instead of `App\Department` in create.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

The typology must be respected as the others have specified, APP\Department is different from App\Department

But Good practices is to create required variables in controller, and just send them to the view, example is:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $departments = App\Department::all();   
        return view('admin.user.create', [
            'departments' => $departments
        ]);
        //return view('admin.user.create', compact('departments'));
    }
```

This type of organization allow you to manipulate data that will be send in your view, you can manage it with more operation on data that will be send. something that can be confused if it is found in the view.

Comment: Take a look on laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#introduction